# Query between multiple rows mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm totally new to mysql.

I'm trying to determine a query that would check my database for matches, when myid = hisid, and hisid=myid between different rows.

I understand why this code:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE myid = hisid
```

Didn't work, because what I'm looking for is in different rows.

An example table:

```
id| myid| hisid|
__|_____|______|
1 |  1  |  2   |
2 |  1  |  3   |
3 |  2  |  1   |
```

The output should be id 1 and id 2.

Thanks everybody in advance!

Comment: Maybe explain why the output should be `id 1` and `id 2`. Your query as it stands selects all the rows where `myid` and `hisid` are equal - which is no rows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll join the table to itself:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t1
   INNER JOIN table t2
      ON t1.myid = t2.hisid
```

Comment: Would it be ok to do it with an OR ,@JNevill?

Comment: Yes. `t1.myid = t2.hisid OR t1.hisid = t2.myid` would work fine here.

Answer (score 1):

For such cases, use Join operation.
Query will be:

```
    SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON  table1.myid=table2.hisid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from `table` t
where exists(select 1 from `table`
             where hisid = t.myid)
```